# How to get value of checked item from CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have used a CheckedListBox over my WinForm in C#. I have bounded this control as shown below -

```
chlCompanies.DataSource = dsCompanies.Tables[0];
chlCompanies.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
chlCompanies.ValueMember = "ID";
```

I can get the indices of checked items, but how can i get checked item text and value. Rather how can i enumerate through CheckedItems accessing Text and Value?

Thanks for sharing your time.

Comment: The underlying `Value` of an item should be calculated regarding to `ValueMember`, regardless of the type of data source. The data source may be a `DataTable` or a `List` and the type of the item may be `DataRowView` or `object` or simple data types.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56174135/3110834) shares a general solution.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Cast it back to its original type, which will be a DataRowView if you're binding a table, and you can then get the Id and Text from the appropriate columns:

```
foreach(object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
     DataRowView castedItem = itemChecked as DataRowView;
     string comapnyName = castedItem["CompanyName"];
     int? id = castedItem["ID"];
}
```

Comment: My friend, I think you have not gone thoroughly with my question. I am using CheckedListBox. I dont need any selection, instead i want checked items. The property just gives the value of selected item only.

Comment: @w69rdy: The `CheckedItems` property is an array of `objects`. An `object` doesn't have a `SelectedValue` property, they can be anything.

Comment: @w69rdy: I am getting castedItem as null.

Comment: @w69rdy: I found the solution. I just replaced DataRow with DataRowView. Its now working. Can you please update your solution.

Comment: @w69rdy: Please update your answer changing DataRow with DataRowView. Its working now. I am accepting your solution.

Answer (score 14):

EDIT: I realized a little late that it was bound to a DataTable. In that case the idea is the same, and you can cast to a `DataRowView` then take its `Row` property to get a `DataRow` if you want to work with that class.

```
foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    var row = (item as DataRowView).Row;
    MessageBox.Show(row["ID"] + ": " + row["CompanyName"]);
}
```

You would need to cast or parse the items to their strongly typed equivalents, or use the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` namespace to use the [`DataRowExtensions.Field` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) demonstrated below:

```
foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    var row = (item as DataRowView).Row;
    int id = row.Field<int>("ID");
    string name = row.Field<string>("CompanyName");
    MessageBox.Show(id + ": " + name);
}
```

---

You need to cast the item to access the properties of your class.

```
foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    var company = (Company)item;
    MessageBox.Show(company.Id + ": " + company.CompanyName);
}
```

Alternately, you could use the [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension method to get strongly typed results back without explicitly casting within the loop:

```
foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType<Company>())
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.Id + ": " + item.CompanyName);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can iterate over the `CheckedItems` property:

```
foreach(object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    MyCompanyClass company = (MyCompanyClass)itemChecked;    
    MessageBox.Show("ID: \"" + company.ID.ToString());
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems.aspx

Comment: Thanks Evan! But my question is how to get the associate ID of the checked item?

Comment: @IrfanRaza: See my edited code sample. You would need to cast each item that was checked to your custom data type to access its specific properties.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (int x in chklstTerms.CheckedIndices)
{
    chklstTerms.SelectedIndex=x;
    termids.Add(chklstTerms.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the all selected Items in a CheckedListBox try this:

In this case ths value is a String but it's run with other type of Object:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myCheckedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (myCheckedListBox.GetItemChecked(i) == true)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("This is the value of ceckhed Item " + myCheckedListBox.Items[i].ToString());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Egypt Development Blog : Get value of checked item in CheckedListBox in vb.net](http://egdev.com/blog/post/2011/09/18/Get-value-of-checked-item-in-CheckedListBox.aspx)

**after bind CheckedListBox with data you can get value of checked items**

```
For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1
                    Dim XDRV As DataRowView = CType(CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(i), DataRowView)
                    Dim XDR As DataRow = XDRV.Row
                    Dim XDisplayMember As String = XDR(CheckedListBox1.DisplayMember).ToString()
                    Dim XValueMember As String = XDR(CheckedListBox1.ValueMember).ToString()
                    MsgBox("DisplayMember : " & XDisplayMember & "   - ValueMember : " & XValueMember )
Next
```

now you can use the value or Display of checked items in CheckedListBox from the 2 variable XDisplayMember And XValueMember in the loop

hope to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

> <sub>I've already posted `GetItemValue` extension method in this post
>   [Get the value for a listbox item by
>   index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38305363/3110834). This extension
>   method will work for all `ListControl` classes including
>   `CheckedListBox`, `ListBox` and `ComboBox`.</sub>

---

None of the existing answers are general enough, but there is a general solution for the problem.

In all cases, the underlying `Value` of an item should be calculated regarding to `ValueMember`, regardless of the type of data source.

The data source of the `CheckedListBox` may be a `DataTable` or it may be a list which contains objects, like a `List<T>`, so the items of a `CheckedListBox` control may be `DataRowView`, Complex Objects, Anonymous types, primary types and other types.

**GetItemValue Extension Method**

We need a `GetItemValue` which works similar to `GetItemText`, but return an object, the underlying value of an item, regardless of the type of object you added as item.

We can create `GetItemValue` [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) to get item value which works like [`GetItemText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
public static class ListControlExtensions
{
    public static object GetItemValue(this ListControl list, object item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(list.ValueMember))
            return item;

        var property = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(item)[list.ValueMember];
        if (property == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(
                string.Format("item doesn't contain '{0}' property or column.",
                list.ValueMember));
        return property.GetValue(item);
    }
}
```

Using above method you don't need to worry about settings of `ListBox` and it will return expected `Value` for an item. It works with `List<T>`, `Array`, `ArrayList`, `DataTable`, List of Anonymous Types, list of primary types and all other lists which you can use as data source. Here is an example of usage:

```
//Gets underlying value at index 2 based on settings
this.checkedListBox.GetItemValue(this.checkedListBox.Items[2]);
```

Since we created the `GetItemValue` method as an extension method, when you want to use the method, don't forget to include the namespace in which you put the class.

This method is applicable on `ComboBox` and `CheckedListBox` too.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
  foreach (var item in chlCompanies.CheckedItems){
     item.Value //ID
     item.Text //CompanyName
  }
```

Comment: you should add a little description of what the code does. You are also missing semi-colons in your code.

Answer (score -2):

You may try this :

```
string s = "";

foreach(DataRowView drv in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    s += drv[0].ToString()+",";
}
s=s.TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Madhuchhanda.  How is your answer substantively different from the other answers already provided?  Best not to provide duplicate answers as it merely adds to the noise and makes it more confusing for people seeking help.