# how can i get the selected value of a multi-item checklistbox, c#, winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, checklistbox

so, I have a checkListBox that i'm trying to get the value member of the checked boxes. Currently, I can get the selectedValue of one item. If multiple items are checked, i get the same selectedValue for each.

The box is populated like so...

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.cs);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_getCustomers, cn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "usp_getCustomers");
chkListCustomer.DataSource = ds;
chkListCustomer.DisplayMember = "usp_getCustomers.name";
chkListCustomer.ValueMember = "usp_getCustomers.id";
chkListCustomer.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

On a button click, this is what i'm doing to TRY and get the selected values. It gives me the right ID for one item, but if multiple items are checked, it gives the same ID back for all.

```
foreach (int indexChecked in chkListCustomer.CheckedIndices)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Index#: " + indexChecked.ToString() + ", is checked. Checked state is:" + chkListCustomer.SelectedValue.ToString()  + ".");   
}
```

example output is:

```
"Index#: 1, is checked. Checked state is:984"  
"Index#: 2, is checked. Checked state is:984"  
"Index#: 3, is checked. Checked state is:984"
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: found my answer from a similar post answered by Ahmad Mageed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875540/how-to-get-value-of-checked-item-from-checkedlistbox  will update it as the answer later when SO will allow me to...my rep is under 100, can't self answer for a while. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modified a piece of code found on [SO on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875540/how-to-get-value-of-checked-item-from-checkedlistbox) from Ahmad Mageed. This gives me each

```
    foreach (object itemChecked in chkListPatients.CheckedItems) 
    {
        DataRow row = (itemChecked as DataRowView).Row;
        string id = row[0].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(id);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach (int indexChecked in chkListCustomer.CheckedIndices)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Index#: " + indexChecked.ToString() +
        ", is checked. Checked state is:" +
        chkListCustomer.Items[indexChecked].ToString()  + ".");   
}
```

Comment: this returns  "System.Data.DataRowView" instead of a number

Comment: @dave k: Then you need to cast `chkListCustomer.Items[indexChecked]` to `DataRowView` and inspect that object.  I can't tell just from the code how the value object is created, since it's done with binding.  But that `DataRowView` object contains the value you are looking for somewhere.  You just need to figure out how to extract it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually need the index, you could simply use [the `CheckedItems` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems.aspx):

```
foreach (DataRowView checkedItem in chkListCustomer.CheckedItems)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Checked item: "
        + checkedItem[chkListCustomer.ValueMember].ToString()
        + ".");
}
```

Comment: this returns "System.Data.DataRowView" instead of a number...and you're right, i don't need the index, i was just stealing the sample code off MSDN

Comment: @dave k: Aha, then you need to index that view to get the data you are interested in.  Let me edit the answer.

Comment: i get an error, usp_getCustomers.id is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table usp_getCustomers

Comment: Seems you're stuck at the same place as cdhowie's answer.  I haven't used this control, so I don't really know how to help you further :)  Maybe try `int` indices (such as 0), `DisplayMember`, or column names from your table.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
chkListCustomer.GetItemCheckState(indexChecked).ToString()
```

instead of

```
chkListCustomer.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

More info on MSDN about [CheckedIndices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkedindices.aspx) and [CheckedListBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx).

Also you can iterate through the [`.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.items.aspx) property:

```
foreach(object itemChecked in chkListCustomer.CheckedItems) {
    // Use the IndexOf method to get the index of an item.
    MessageBox.Show("Item with title: \"" + itemChecked.ToString() + 
                    "\", is checked. Checked state is: " + 
        chkListCustomer.GetItemCheckState(chkListCustomer.Items.IndexOf(itemChecked)).ToString() + ".");
    MessageBox.Show(itemChecked.ToString())
}
```

Comment: this only tells me if the item is checked, not it's value.

Comment: @dave k try to investigate the `itemChecked.ToString()`