# How to add value from checkedlistbox into database using stored procedure c# windows forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying  to add checked values from checkedlistbox using stored procedure and C#

```
 public static void CreateDrugsListBox(CheckedListBox DrugsList) 
   {
       try
       {
           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"connection");
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertData_DrugsListBox", con);
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

           con.Open();
           foreach (string  itemchecked in DrugsList.CheckedItems) 
           {
               cmd.Parameters.Clear();           
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrugsValue", itemchecked); 
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

           }
           con.Close();
      }

       catch (Exception ex)
       {

           MessageBox.Show("Error"+ex, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

       }

   }
```

it displays an error like:

```
errorSystem.invalidcastException: imposible to make a cast of an object type System.Data.DataRowView in type System.String
```

Comment: What's the datatype of your field in database ? "DrugsValue"

Comment: type varchar in database

Comment: DrugsList.CheckedItems are not of Datatype string..

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875540/how-to-get-value-of-checked-item-from-checkedlistbox

Comment: thanks @apomene for your reply. I follow this link but i get the same problem :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           insert(list1);

        }
    private void insert(CheckedListBox list1)
     {
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
      {
      try
      {
     conn.ConnectionString = "data source=servername;User ID=user_name;Password=password;initial catalog=database_name;integrated security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertData_CityListBox", conn);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      for (int i = 0; i < list1.Items.Count; i++)
      {
       if (list1.GetItemChecked(i))
       {
   string str = (string)list1.Items[i]; //Or try  list1.Items[i].ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city_code", str);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
    }
            conn.Close();
         }
      catch(Exception e1)
        {

           }

      }
    }
```

Stored procedure

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertData_CityListBox] 
(@city_code varchar(50) ) 
AS BEGIN 

insert into city(city_code) values (@city_code)
 END;
```

Form Screen
[image]

Table after data insert

[image]

Comment: same problem " errorSystem.invalidcastException: imposible to make a cast of an object type System.Data.DataRowView in type System.String"

Comment: Can u post the code where u specifying the datatype of parameter "@Drugsvalue" also the procedure using to insert the data..

Comment: my procedure is : `create PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertData_DrugsListBox] (@DrugsValue varchar(50) )
 
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @PatientId int = (select IDENT_CURRENT('Patient') );

 insert into Drugs (DrugsValue, FK_Patient )
 values (@DrugsValue, @PatientId  )
END`  
@Sachu

Comment: Dear leila.net. find my edited answer..an example done in my environment and its working fine.

Comment: Happy to hear it helped...what you changed?